# What does down the hall mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “Good night,” said Adam.
>  She did not answer him.
>  At the top
>   of the first flight he looked back. Her head was raised, and now her
>   chin made a shadow on her throat and her eyes had no pupils.
>  His
>   room smelled of dust dampened and dried many times. He picked a match
>   from his block and scratched it on the side of the block. He lighted
>   the shank of candle in the japanned candlestick and regarded the
>   bed-as spineless as a hammock and covered with a dirty patchwork
>   quilt, the cotton batting spilling from the edges.
>  The porch
>   steps complained again, and Adam knew the woman would be standing in
>   her doorway ready to spray inhospitality on the new arrival.
>  Adam
>   sat down in a straight chair and put his elbows on his knees and
>   supported his chin in his hands. A roomer **down the hall** began a
>   patient, continuing cough against the quiet night.
>  (John
>   Steinbeck, East of Eden)

Does the highlighted part mean this boarding house has rooms in the first floor as well as the second; and the roomer is in a room in the first floor? What does the ‘down’ mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the definition of "*down*" as a preposition [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/down). "*He is walking down the street*" will mean "*He is walking **along** the street*". "*He lives down the hall*" will mean "*He lives on the same floor, along the hallway, a few doors away*."