# Meaning of something down the hall

Tags: american-english

Does the phrase "guest room down the hall" mean a guestroom located at the end of the hall or a guestroom along the hall?

Comment: Could mean either.

Comment: I don't think down the hall means at the end of the hall. You are standing somewhere and someone says: It's down the hall. Farther along the hall than where you are standing. If something is at the end of the hall, you would usually say that: It's at the end of the hall.

Comment: Why don't OPs accept perfectly usable answers?

Comment: @Lambie New user

Answer (score 1):

Either.  What it clearly doesn't mean is "guest room before the hall".  It shouldn't mean "guest room at the beginning of the hall", but I know of at least one native English speaker who used it that way.  If someone who speaks carefully says it, it's probably at least a third of the way along the hall, but it's not a very exact statement for most people.

[What does down the hall mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6963/what-does-down-the-hall-mean)

[down the hall to the left](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171120/down-the-hall-to-the-left)

Answer (score 1):

down the hall
[like down the street, down the road, etc.]

are spoken usages and call for the speaker to be describing something to another speaker.

**It's relative to where the two people are standing**.

**Both mean at a point farther along from where they are standing**. But neither means: at the end of a hall or street because speakers would then actually say:

at the end of the street
OR

at the end of the hall.

Also, please note: people use up here too. Again, it depends on the perception of the speaker. **You can perceive a person or thing to be up or down from you as speaker.**

If I am at the end of a hall, I could say: The lady's room is up the hall or down the hall. Both are understood to mean at a point farther along than where you are standing.

Therefore, what **can** have the same meaning is up and down, and not that down means end.

In some circumstances such as a road on a hill, up and down the hill or road on a hill tend to be easier to identify in terms of up and down.