# a man down the hall

Tags: grammaticality, usage

She opened the door a crack and looked out to see a man **down** the hall.

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but is "down" OK here or can it only be used if you add e.g. "walking" in front of it?

She opened the door a crack and looked out to see a man **walking down** the hall.

Comment: Related: [Why do you always “go down the street”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/49615/9161)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does down the hall mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6963/what-does-down-the-hall-mean)

Answer (score 1):

> She opened the door a crack and looked out to see a man **down** the hall.

> She opened the door a crack and looked out to see a man **walking down** the hall.

The 2 examples are fine but different.  The 1st may mean a man standing down the hall.

Both forms, with and without a verb before **down**, are used.

From Google Dictionary

> down1
> /daʊn/
> preposition: down

> at or to the part of (a river or stream) that is nearer the sea.
> "a dozen miles or so down the Thames"

> moving or at a point further along the course of (something).
> "he lived down the street"